# How to make swape effect on UITableView when call function reloadData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, slide, reloaddata

I want to make swipe effect on a UITableView when we call function reloadData.

Actually there is list of categories on the top of page when I click any of those category button its content loaded in the page and its working fine. But now I want to make a slide effect there. If User click on button product should be loaded having left to right/right to left slide effect.

Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link. Hope it may help you and you get the answer from the link. [How would you implement an UITableView that detects horizontal swipes in order to allow paging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342758/how-would-you-implement-an-uitableview-that-detects-horizontal-swipes-in-order-to)